# Two divergent series conspiring?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $a_n=2^{2n}\binom{2n}n^{-1}$. [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) shows that $a_n\sim \sqrt{\pi n}$, thus
$$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\pi}{2a_n}\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{a_n}{2n+1}$$
are both divergent series. However, their difference should converge with terms of order $\sim\frac1{n^{3/2}}$.

> **Question.** In fact, is this true?
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{2a_n}-\frac{a_n}{2n+1}\right)=1.$$

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you have some numerical evidence that suggests this is the case? (otherwise this seems wildly improbable).

Comment: Absolutely, yes.

Comment: Experiment makes it clear that the terms in the sum are  $\sqrt{\pi/n}(n^{-1}/8-3n^{-2}/32+O(n^{-3}))$.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We have
  $$ f(x):=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{a_n} =
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$
and
  $$ g(x):=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a_n}{2n+1}x^{2n} =
  \frac{\sin^{-1}x}  {x\sqrt{1-x^2}}. $$
It is routine to compute that
  $$ \lim_{x\to 1-}\left(\frac 12\pi f(x)-g(x)\right)=1 $$
and then apply [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem).

Comment: Richard: that is cool and clean.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the difference of the two series converges absolutely. First, note that the [refined Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates)
$$ n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n(1+O(n^{-1}))$$
yields $a_n=\sqrt{\pi n}(1+O(n^{-1}))$, hence also $a_n^2=\pi n(1+O(n^{-1}))$. Therefore, 
$$ \left|\frac{\pi}{2a_n}-\frac{a_n}{2n+1}\right| = \frac{\bigl|\pi(2n+1)-2\pi n(1+O(n^{-1}))\bigr|}{(4n+2)a_n}=\frac{O(1)}{(4n+2)a_n}=O(n^{-3/2}),$$
and the claim follows by the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3/2}$.

**Added.** I missed that the main point of the question was the evaluation of the difference series. For this, see Richard Stanley's response.

Comment: This analysis is almost what I commented on in the question, although not in detail. Anyhow, the convergence was clear. The main question is to show the sum actually equal to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I was too tired when I read your question and missed that the main point was the evaluation of the sum. I was also mislead by you saying "should converge" instead of saying "converges". I am glad Richard Stanley has clarified the situation, and I agree his proof is cool and clean.

Comment: Of course, I thank you for the details in your answer.